# Is there an option like "Enable absolute pointing device" for VMWare Fusion?

Tags: vmware-fusion

VirtualBox offers this option which allows to share the pointer between host and guest without having to press any host key (i.e., treating the virtual machine windows like any other application window).

Is there something similar for VMWare? I'm sick of having to press the host key each time I want the mouse pointer to leave the VM and give the control back to the host.

Comment: I think the vmware tools for the guest OS allows that - what guest os?

Comment: Gentoo. Isn't there any setting in the VMM?

Comment: @GaretJax - You have to install the guest additions. Mount the VMWare guest additions image, and install them. That's all you need. (Well, and a Xorg. hah.)